# N Channel MOSFET high side switching

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, waveform

I am attempting to design a powerful, yet efficient soft switching fullbridge converter. Achieving that requires high side switching with an N Channel MOSFET.

Now while I have succesfully achieved a drain to source voltage drop of but 0.2mV when a stable dc voltage is applied. However, when a switching signal of 100kHz is applied to the gate of the MOSFET, via a Darlington transistor (see diagram below), strange things start to happen. 
With strange things I mean: [image]

This is my first attempt at high side switching with an N Channel MOSFET and I am completely lost on what I should do to fix this. Why is it not a pretty square wave like the signal? My guess is that the gate is charging too slow.

As additional information, this is the circuitry of the test setup: [image: circuit]

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The only means you have of charging the gate source capacitor (possibly somewhere in the realm of 1 nF), is a 4 kohm resistor. Go work how long this takes to charge. You need a push pull driver for high speed switching.

Comment: A push-pull driver, ofcourse! I'm going to try it out now! Thank you! I'll come again if it works!

Comment: Hold on, the 30 volt supply for the gate is too high. Got for 15 volts or you'll pop the mosfet

Comment: I may have rounded the voltages to their nearby tens, but i'll make sure not to cross the +/- 20V difference! Thank you.

Comment: You're suggesting the Vgs to be 15V right?

Comment: what is being suggested is what the datasheet permits and there is a very high chance it is 20V max and thus 15V is recomended

Comment: How would I solve this? Since my input voltage will be high (probably in the 25V). However, if there is a 15V recommended Vgs, 40V would be the recommended gate voltage. This is a problem when the MOSFET turns of, then the Vgs is practically 40V. How is this solved without using commercial drivers?

Comment: Read what you wrote and ask yourself if it makes sence. I don't understand the 40 volt bit.

Comment: ok I follow you. You need a bootstrapped push pull driver. Fairchild and international rectifier make them but there will be others. They steal a bit of output power and create a higher supply rail automatically.

Comment: Excuse me for the vagueness, as I said, I would return with more results. I do have something better, but still not good enough I think. [this](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Amplifiers/images/complementary-pair.gif) is the push-pull configuration. [This](http://i.imgur.com/TKgceB5.jpg) is the new waveform. As you can see, much better. However, the drain seems to be floating at 5V in the off state as well. Any suggestions on how to make this a better square wave?

Comment: That isn't your circuit, its a push pull stage driving a speaker. You need a proper bootstrapped driver. Regards the waveforms they do look odd but I can't tell which waveform is which and what they relate to on the schematic that shows the speaker.

Comment: Nope, it isn't, it's the same configuration though. [this](https://i.imgur.com/PXADtn3.png) would be the exact circuit.  Oh I am sorry, I thought I had explained the waveforms above, I did not. The top one is the drain-source waveform and the second is gate-source.

Comment: Q2 is upside down. It will partially work like this but it's not ideal. Your scope waveforms look like you need the probes adjusting for square wave flatness. Do you have a 1 kHz square wave point on your scope to connect the probes to so you can adjust them?

Comment: Yes, it does, but I need it to drive a switching power supply at atleast 2kW. That's why it needs to be a good square wave and I can't use ICs. Oh, the probes are perfectly well compensated. This is what I get from the MOSFET, that's why I am asking you if you have any advice on how to fix it. The signal is perfectly square as well.

Comment: It doesn't look square.

Comment: No, that's the gate-source and drain-source, the signal comes from an Arduino. Outputting a 100kHz signal. It's exactly the problem, it isn't square and it isn't the scope or the signal.

Comment: Does it look square when it isn't connected to your circuit?

Comment: It looks pretty square to me :) http://i.imgur.com/UL8jiIB.jpg

Comment: Okay, so I did [this](https://i.imgur.com/xvThkU1.png) in LTSpice and it produced [these waveforms](https://i.imgur.com/G2xmV7n.png). It seems to work fine, do you have additional comments to add to this? I do not fully trust it to be honest.